# Ruby copy file by extension

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to execute below command Ruby block from Chef and giving below error.

```
FileUtils.cp_r Dir.glob "#{node['default']['home']}/standalone/deployments/'*.ear'", "#{node['default']['default_backup_path']}/my_bkp_#{time}", :noop => true, :verbose => true
```

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you need parenthesis for your `Dir.glob` method, it's taking just the first argument being passed, and the rest, is being considered as a `FileUtils.cp_r` argument, try with:

```
FileUtils.cp_r(
  Dir.glob(
    "#{node['default']['home']}/standalone/deployments/'*.ear'", 
    "#{node['default']['default_backup_path']}/my_bkp_#{time}"
  ),
  'destination/',
  noop: true,
  verbose: true
)
```

You're passing two `patterns` argument to the `glob` method, that's the reason of the error:

> no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Try just using `cp_r` for each pattern, like:

```
FileUtils.cp_r(
  Dir.glob("#{node['default']['home']}/standalone/deployments/'*.ear'"), 
  'destination/',
  noop: true,
  verbose: true
)

FileUtils.cp_r(
  Dir.glob("#{node['default']['default_backup_path']}/my_bkp_#{time}"),
  'destination/',
  noop: true,
  verbose: true
)
```

I think your goal is to iterate get the elements in

- `"#{node['default']['home']}/standalone/deployments/'*.ear'"`
- `"#{node['default']['default_backup_path']}/my_bkp_#{time}"`

so you could iterate over these two directories, and use this pattern within the `Dir.glob` method, like:

```
patterns = [
  "#{node['default']['home']}/standalone/deployments/'*.ear'", 
  "#{node['default']['default_backup_path']}/my_bkp_#{time}"
]
patterns.each do |pattern|
  FileUtils.cp_r Dir.glob(pattern), 'destination/', noop: true, verbose: true
end
```

Where `'destination/'` is the folder in which the elements will be copied, that you're missing.

Or in the case you want to use the `default_backup_path` folder as destination, then you don't need the `Dir.glob` method, just add it as the `dest` parameter, as a String

```
FileUtils.cp_r(
  Dir.glob("#{node['default']['home']}/standalone/deployments/'*.ear'"),
  "#{node['default']['default_backup_path']}/my_bkp_#{time}",
  noop: true,
  verbose: true
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have tried this and its giving me an error saying "had an error: TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer"

Comment: So, the error has changed, doesn't it point you to what line is giving the error?

Comment: Yeah. but its the same line number. I'm new to Ruby here. so little bit struggling with this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sebastian. this is worked fine! appreciate your support.